# How do I make a ticketing system for my bot using the discord-buttons npm package?

Tags: button, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

So I am working on a Ticketing System for my Discord bot, and my code worked before, but I messed it up, and now it doesn't work.

**What I want it to do:** When people click the button([discord-buttons](https://npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons)) I want it to first check for a category named "Tickets", then make a new channel called "(username)-ticket", and finally, send a embed in the channel that was just made.

**What actually happens:** The code just says "Cannot read channels of undefined", and does not work.

**My Code:**

```js
client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
    if (button.id == "ticket") {
      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed;
      embed.setTitle('Created Ticket')
      embed.setDescription('Successfully created your ticket.')
      await button.reply.send({ embed: embed }, true);
      let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed
      embed2.setTitle(`Hello, ${button.clicker.user.username}`)
      embed2.setDescription('Someone will be with you shortly. To close the ticket, press the ❌ emoji.')
      embed2.setFooter('Ticketing System created by FireyJS#6969')
      const guild = button.clicker.guild
if (guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === 'tickets')) {
  const category = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === 'tickets')
 guild.channels.create(`${button.clicker.user.username}-ticket`, { reason : 'Needed to make a ticket lol' }).then(channel => { 
 channel.setParent(category)
 channel.send(embed2)
 }).then(message => { message.react('❌') })
 } else {
   message.channel.send('Make a category named ``Tickets`` to get started with ticketing!')
 }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `button.clicker` object does not have a `guild` property, but `button` on its own does.  Try defining `guild` as `button.guild` instead of what you currently have!